# Print array in visual c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Hi I need print my array string but I don't know 
this is the code the array 
is on string and I need print all position

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    string jmena[8]; 

    //populate array:
    jmena[0] = "Ruzicka Vit";
    jmena[1] = "Bily Saruman";
    jmena[2] = "Veliky Saruman";
    jmena[3] = "Calculator Veliky";
    jmena[4] = "Jakekoliv Jmeno";
    jmena[5] = "Nekdo Veliky";
    jmena[6] = "Ahoj Vitek";
    jmena[7] = "Whatever Name";

    int hola = 0;     

    cout << "Nombres " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {

        cout << jmena[i] ; // I have error here IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands

    }
    cin >> hola;

}
```

When using array type char only print the last letter of every word

Comment: cout << jmena[i]; ???

Comment: But you don't actually *print* the values from the array?

Comment: Also, the last line of your question is a little vague/unclear.

Comment: Try to #include <string> and use cout <<

Comment: @AbhishekBansal thanks work nice

Comment: You are declaring 8 strings but assigning 9.  Array location [8] is actually the 9th slot, which goes outside of your array capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `<string>` inclusion, it defines the `operator<<` for `string` to be used with `cout`

Comment: This work fine
Try to #include <string> and use cout

Answer (score 0):

You access the array content (`jmena[i]`) but don't display anything. You need to display the content: `cout << jmena[i];`.

Comment: when use cout << jmena[i];
I have this error
IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands

Comment: Not sure where your `string` definition comes from. Try to include `<string>`, and maybe use `std::string` instead of just `string`.

Answer (score 0):

to output all of your strings, try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) {
    cout << jmena[i] << endl;
}
```

this will require you include the string header. Add `#include <string>` near the top